# How to use jQuery click function to delete closest div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove the parent `p` tag when the cross button is clicked.

My HTML structure is like this :

```js
jQuery('.delete').click(function() {
  jQuery(this).closest('.question-list').remove()
});

jQuery('.add-question-btn').click(function() {
jQuery("#add-question-div-parent").append("<p class='add-question-div' style='position: relative'><input type='text' class='add-ques-text' placeholder='Add Question'><span><i class='fa fa-times cls' aria-hidden='true'></i></span></p>");
});
        
jQuery('.cls').click(function() {
   jQuery('.add-question-div').remove()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="question-list">Here is my question.Here is my question.Here is my question.
 <span><i class="fa fa-times delete" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
</p>
<div id="add-question-div-parent" class="full-width"></div>
<button class="add-question-btn">+</button>
```

`.add-question-div` this has been added successfully after `'.add-question-btn'` button has clicked, but unfortunately i'm not able to remove `.add-question-div`  when i click on `.cls`.

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Use `$("#add-question-div-parent").on('click', '.cls', function() {
  $(this).closest('.add-question-div').remove()
})`

Comment: Thanks, Its working :)

Answer (score 0):

The `.cls` element is added dynamically so the `click` event is not associated at the time of page load so use `$(document).on('click','.cls', function(){...});`. You also need to delete the particular `add-question-div` when the icon is clicked so use `$(this).closest('.add-question-div').remove();`

```js
$('.delete').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.question-list').remove()
});

$('.add-question-btn').click(function() {
$("#add-question-div-parent").append("<p class='add-question-div' style='position: relative'><input type='text' class='add-ques-text' placeholder='Add Question'><span><i class='fa fa-times cls' aria-hidden='true'>X</i></span></p>");
});

$(document).on('click','.cls', function() {
   $(this).closest('.add-question-div').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="question-list">Here is my question.Here is my question.Here is my question.
  <span><i class="fa fa-times delete" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
</p>
<div id="add-question-div-parent" class="full-width"></div>
<button class="add-question-btn">+</button>
```